# Unable to setup hystrix dashboard in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hystrix

I am trying to setup a hystrix dashboard for my java spring boot application. After starting the application i get proxy opening message in console but nothing happens.

```
Proxy opening connection to: http://localhost:9083/actuator/hystrix.stream
```

In dashboard it says Loading... and nothing gets displayed...see image attached at bottom.

Also when i hit this url http://localhost:9083/actuator/hystrix.stream in the browser no data is displayed just constant empty pings. Like

ping:

ping:

ping:

...

Code changes that i had done are

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/elasticsearch/{numberOfInstances}/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void ingestMip4DataToES(@PathVariable("numberOfInstances") int numberOfInstances,
            @PathVariable("name") String name) {

        if(numberOfInstances > 1) {
            List<IdentifiableType> identifiableTypes = generateMultipleInstancesOfMip4Data(numberOfInstances, name);
            if(!identifiableTypes.isEmpty()) {
                dumpBulkMip4DataToES(identifiableTypes);                
            }
        } else {
            IdentifiableType identifiableType = generateSingleInstanceOfMip4Data(name);
            if(identifiableType != null) {
                dumpMip4DataToES(identifiableType);             
            }
        }
    }
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackForMip4SingleDataGeneration")
    private IdentifiableType generateSingleInstanceOfMip4Data(String name) {
        String url = GENERATOR_URL + name;

        ResponseEntity<IdentifiableType> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, IdentifiableType.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }

private IdentifiableType fallbackForMip4SingleDataGeneration() {
        logger.info("Calling fallback method for mip4 data generation as request to service failed.");
        return null;
    }
```

Included required annotations on main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrixDashboard
public class InsaneMip4ElasticSearchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InsaneMip4ElasticSearchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Resource file contains following entries

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

And for pom file below entries were made

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Hystrix dashboard looks like below
[image]

Comment: make sure the contorl reaches this function `generateSingleInstanceOfMip4Data`. without the flow reaching the function with HystrixCommand even once, you will not see anything

Comment: Sorry but i couldn't understand what you mean

Comment: once u start the application. when is this function called `generateSingleInstanceOfMip4Data` ? on doing what action? I am saying this method should be called for you to see something in the dashboard. are you doing some action which causes this function to be called. if not do it.

Comment: yes, this function is called from another function, i have just edited the code for your reference.
When i execute the mapped url with request mapping then too nothing happens.

Comment: are you sure you are hitting this endpoint /elasticsearch/{numberOfInstances}/{name} with numberofInstances <1 becos, only then you method generateSingleInstanceOfMip4Data  is called

Comment: http://localhost:9083/mip4/elasticsearch/1/CUnitType so as you see here the numberOfInstances is 1 and method generateSingleInstanceOfMip4Data  gets called

Answer (score 0):

The dashboard was empty because of wrong configuration i made. HystrixCommand should be attached to methods that are annotated with RequestMapping. This is because Hystrix monitors api end points.

So doing below changes made things work for me.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackForMip4DataGeneration")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/elasticsearch/{numberOfInstances}/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void ingestMip4DataToES(@PathVariable("numberOfInstances") int numberOfInstances,
            @PathVariable("name") String name) {

        if(numberOfInstances > 1) {
            List<IdentifiableType> identifiableTypes = generateMultipleInstancesOfMip4Data(numberOfInstances, name);
            if(!identifiableTypes.isEmpty()) {
                dumpBulkMip4DataToES(identifiableTypes);                
            }
        } else {
            IdentifiableType identifiableType = generateSingleInstanceOfMip4Data(name);
            if(identifiableType != null) {
                dumpMip4DataToES(identifiableType);             
            }
        }
    }

    private void fallbackForMip4DataGeneration(int numberOfInstances, String name) {
        logger.info("Calling fallback method for mip4 data generation as request to service failed.");
    }
```

So as you can see, now the @HystrixCommand annotation is applied to ingestMip4DataToES() method because this method has @RequestMapping annotation. Earlier applying @HystrixCommand to generateSingleInstanceOfMip4Data() method was incorrect.

Now when i make a call to http://localhost:9083/mip4/elasticsearch/1/CUnitType, i can see live monitoring for that call on hystrix dashboard.

Remember to access dashboard by http://host:port/hystrix and apply http://host:port/actuator/hystrix.stream in url if using Springboot 2 (2.0.2.RELEASE) to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Please add @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackForMip4SingleDataGeneration") to your @RequestMapping and try to access the @RequestMapping url multiple time. Once you have accessed you desired @RequestMapping url then go to hystrix.stream and you will find the necessary information.